What is the best procedure if the rudder falls off?
I've recently looked up American Airlines Flight 587, the second worst aircraft accident in U.S history. The main cause of the accident is the separation of the vertical stabilizer and rudder from the aircraft. This helped me understand that loss of a vertical stabilizer is not survivable. However, I have been wondering, is separation of only the rudder and not the whole vertical stabilizer survivable? By survivable, I mean to regain at least partial control of the aircraft, sufficient enough for a controlled, survivable emergency landing. If so, what procedures will maximize the chances of regaining control of the aircraft? Are there any experienced pilots here who can tell me? I will greatly appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Note: I'm not looking for speculation, explanation or description about the reasons of crash and course of event of American Airlines Flight 587. Rather, I'm asking whether or not a loss of rudder is survivable and if so, what procedures will increase the chances of survival.

Airliners don't need rudder to maneuver.

@CamilleGoudeseune *when both engines are operating and you're not landing with significant crosswind. Engine failure, particularly during full-thrust takeoff with light loads, is the dimensioning case for the vertical stabilizer and rudder.

@CamilleGoudeseune but for coordinated turns they do.

Mostly I just wanted to link to a related set of answers.  The "don't need rudder" summary of those can't catch all the exceptions, of course.

Avoid turns. Do not bank or roll. Continue to fly straight ahead to the accident site.

Aircraft can be flown without a rudder if the vertical stabilizer is still there. There are many pictures of aircraft landing safely after losing the rudder only, and still having the vertical stabilizer at least partially intact. To answer this for yourself, go fly in a Cessna "spam can" (152, 172) and don't touch the rudder pedals during the entire flight. Unless you do something really bizarre that would kill you with or without a rudder, the aircraft will fly, but your turns will be uncoordinated and you will not be able to execute a side slip to get down in a hurry, or crab the aircraft to compensate for a crosswind during landing.
American Airlines Flight 587 was uncontrollable because the entire vertical stabilizer with the rudder was ripped off. Both the rudder hinges and the bolts securing the stabilizer failed.

Thanks, your answer exactly is what I'm looking for! So the real culprit of American Airlines Flight 587 and similar accidents are because of the detachment of the vertical stabilizer, not rudder. I originally didn't knew that losing a rudder will not cause a crash. Thanks for telling me!
